# PayPal IPN - is there a list of all vars you can send in the form?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've searched for the past two hours, including on here, but it seems like PayPal has hidden everything in order to promote their "build a buy button" link.

Is there any documentation on what all the variables are that you can post to paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

like it says:

> This appendix provides reference information for **all** HTML variables supported by any kind of PayPal Payments Standard payment button: